# Find the projection of $U$ onto $V$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm really stuck on this precalc problem: Find the projection of $u$ onto $v$ if $u=(-3,3)$ and $v=(-2,5)$.

Comment: The _orthogonal_ projection, I suppose? What have you done with the problem before you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $\text{proj}\vec{u}_\vec{v} = \left(\dfrac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||^2}\right)\vec{v} = \dfrac{(-3)(-2)+3\cdot 5}{(-2)^2+5^2}\left(-2,5\right) = \left(\dfrac{-42}{29},\dfrac{105}{29}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a formula to the effect of
$$
\text{proj}_v(u) =  \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v} v
$$